Expectation of exponential of random matrices
Let $G$ be an $N \times N$ matrix with i.i.d entries from $\mathcal{N}\left(0, 1/N\right)$:
$$
\mbox{What is}\quad
\mathbb{E}\left[\,{\rm e}^{Gt}\,\right]\ ?
$$

In $\underline{simulations}$, I find that this expectation appears to be proportional to the identity matrix: How does one show this, and how does the prefactor scale with $t$ ?.
Ultimately, for the application I'm interested in, I would also like to compute the expectation of
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\,{\rm e}^{\tilde{G}t}\,\right]
\quad \mbox{where}\quad
\tilde{G} = G + e_{1}e_{1}^\top
$$
is a rank-one perturbation of the random matrix by the outer product of the first basis vector.
Is there a simple way to compute this expectation ?.
Perhaps approximately when $N$ is large ?.


@coiso It's a gaussian matrix.

notice that a multiplication of i.i.d. centered Gaussian variables is also centered, and also the odd power of a centered Gaussian variable is still centered. Can you conclude from here?

(Too long for a comment)
Using Einstein's convention on repeated indices, one has $(G^n)_{ij} = G_{k_0k_1} \cdots G_{k_{n-1}k_n}$, with $k_0 = i$ and $k_n = j$, where $G_{\mu\nu} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) \;\forall \mu,\nu = 1,\ldots N$. Then, the quantity $\Bbb{E}[(G^n)_{ij}]$ can be decomposed with the help of Wick-Isserlis theorem, in such a way that only terms made of identical pairs will contribute. Since all the entries $G_{\mu\nu}$ are iid, one has $\Bbb{E}[G^n] = 0$ when $n$ is odd, obviously. When $n$ is even, you will have to enumerate all the said partitions into contributing pairs, each of them by a term $\sigma^{2n}$ $-$ but I am not sure there exists a simple closed form. You will observe that the transpositions inside a cycle permutation of the indices have to be reversed in order to ensure the fact that the random variables appear twice. In consequence, the non-diagonal components of $G^n$ must vanish in average. Unfortunately, those symmetries, in particular the zero odd-degree moments, may be broken by the pertubation. Finally, you might take a look at the notion of matrix normal distribution, because you are looking for its moment-generating function basically.
